# Gvim font issue

Tags: vim, fonts, monospace

Why do the same font look slightly different in different versions of gvim ?

I was using Monospace 11 font in Gvim 7.3 in which font looked darker/thicker - nice. But once I upgraded to Gvim 7.4 the same Monospace 11 font is looking lighter/thinner - ugly.

Is there any solution other than reverting my version back to 7.3 ?

Comment: Are you using a colorscheme ?

Comment: what is that? I just use syntax highlighting

Comment: I don't use any of those.